# zip outputs in the wrong place when used in a loop

Tags: shell, zsh, zip, for

I have many directories and I want to zip them all.

```bsh
$ mkdir -p one two three
$ touch one/one.txt two/two.txt three/three.txt
$ ls -F
one/  three/  two/
```

I use `zip` and it works as intended:

```bsh
$ zip -r one.zip one
  adding: one/ (stored 0%)
  adding: one/one.txt (stored 0%)
$ ls -F
one/  one.zip  three/  two/
```

But when I used this in a loop using zsh, zip files are created elsewhere.

```bsh
$ for dir in */; do
for> echo "$dir";   
for> zip -r "$dir.zip" "$dir";
for> done   
one/
  adding: one/ (stored 0%)
  adding: one/one.txt (stored 0%)
three/
  adding: three/ (stored 0%)
  adding: three/three.txt (stored 0%)
two/
  adding: two/ (stored 0%)
  adding: two/two.txt (stored 0%)
```

```bsh
$ find . -name "*.zip"
./three/.zip
./two/.zip
./one/.zip
$ ls -F
one/  three/  two/
```

I expected an output like this:

```bsh
$ ls -F
one/  one.zip  three/  three.zip  two/  two.zip
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see it in your output:

```
for dir in */; do
for> echo "$dir";   
for> zip -r "$dir.zip" "$dir";
for> done   
one/
[ . . . ]
```

Since you are doing `for dir in */`, the variable includes the trailing slash. So your `$dir` isn't `one`, it is `one/`. Therefore, when you run `zip -r "$dir.zip" "$dir";`, you are running this:

```
zip -r "one/.zip" "one";
```

So `zip` is doing exactly what you tell it to do. What I think you want is something like this instead:

```
$ for dir in */; do dir=${dir%/}; echo zip -r "$dir.zip" "$dir"; done
zip -r one.zip one
zip -r three.zip three
zip -r two.zip two
```

Comment: It's still the same.

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani did you run it with the `echo` or did you remove the `echo`?

Comment: I did both. With `echo` it produces an output like this: `zip -r one/.zip one/`.

Comment: Okay, my bad. I'm using `zsh`. Should've noted in the question. When I use `bash` it works.

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani for zsh (and yes, please remember to mention things like that, they change everything and you had _explicitly_ tagged the question with `bash`!) change the `dir=${dir///}` to `dir=${dir//\/}` and it should work.

Comment: Or, even better, what @rowboat suggested (thanks!) and which I have now added to my answer since that will work on both bash and zsh (and pretty much everything else).